# Add padding to anchors and style the buttons inside post text editor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, text-editor

I'm using CKEditor4 full version to format, style and add media the posts content.

Sometimes the content contains anchors to link to another page like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/another-page">Another Page</a>
```

I can style that anchor using CKEditor to change the colors, backgrounds, fonts ..etc.

But it would look something like that:

```
    _______________
   | Another Page |
   |______________|
```

So that the background would just wrap the text.

What if I want to add some padding to look like:

```
    ______________________
   |                      |
   |     Another Page     |
   |______________________|
```

Also for buttons, I can't style them.

I know it's a text editor and I can edit the html code, But the one who would use it doesn't know HTML or any programming languages.

So is there is a plugin I can add, another version, or another text editor that provides such features as well as inserting media?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as well as inserting media?

If you wish to embed media using CKEditor, please see below two links:

- https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mediaembed.html
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_media_embed.html

> Sometimes the content contains anchors to link to another page... So is there is a plugin I can add

Your requirement is specific thus I see two solutions here

- If you wish to add special style to particular link you can use Styles Dropdown for that - https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/styles.html. Please simply prepare that style outside of the editor and then add is to `styles.js` file - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_styles.html. You can either add styles or a class name but in that second case you need to add whole class definition to editor `contents.css` file. Finally please note that editor doesn’t submit HTML together with external CSS so your button CSS class used in CKEditor should also be available on page where content will be used.
- Another option is creating a dedicated plugin which will insert special styled links or buttons. How to write plugins has been described here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html